# Is the slater determinant the unique ground state of a system of independent $N$ electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

If $H = \sum_{i = 1}^N h_i$ is the hamiltonian for a system of $N$ independent electrons, is the ground state for this system unique? My tutor seems to think so because he writes «The ground state of a system with $N$ independent electrons, [...] will be an antisymmetrised product of single-particle eigenfunctions of the single-particle Hamiltonians [...]».

Are you able to provide rigorous proof?

EDIT: You can assume that for all $i \in \{ 1,2\cdots,N\}$ we have $h_i \psi_i = \epsilon_i \psi_i$.

Comment: If you do not make any assumptions about the $h_i$, this obviously cannot be proven - just take the case where $h_i = 0$ for all $i$...

Comment: @ACuriousMind is it not clear enough from the question that $h_i$ is not identically zero for each $i \in \{1,\cdots,N\}$?

Comment: I just gave the easiest counterexample - "not identically zero" isn't a strong enough assumption, either (e.g. take all $h_i$ to be multiples of identity). My point is that for a "rigorous proof" you need to provide enough information about $H$ so that the statement you want to prove is actually *true*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have already written in my question that  $h_i = -(1/2)\nabla_i^2 + V_i(r)$, so it is not zero c.f. your first comment.